# Do not display the parameters in the Python Toolbox

Tags: arcpy, python-toolbox, parameters

Now I can use the code to disable the parameter given a certain condition. I wonder if I can make the parameter disappeared if it is disabled. If so, how should I edit my code?

[image]

```
import arcpy

class Toolbox(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.label =  "Step1 toolbox"
        self.alias  = ""

        # List of tool classes associated with this toolbox
        self.tools = [step1]

class step1(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.label       = "Prepare the dataset for the rest of steps"
        self.description = "leave for more " + \
                           "sample " + \
                           "sample."

    def getParameterInfo(self):
        #Define parameter definitions

        # Model Type parameter
        model_type = arcpy.Parameter(
            displayName="Model Type",
            name="model_type",
            datatype="String",
            parameterType="Required",
            direction="Input")

        model_type.filter.list = ["Urban Growth Model",
                                  "Energy Sector Model"]

        # Target county parameter
        target_county = arcpy.Parameter(
            displayName="Target County",
            name="target_county",
            datatype="String",
            parameterType="Required",
            direction="Input",
            enabled=False)

        target_county.filter.list = ["Caldwell",
                                     "Hays",
                                     "Bastrop",
                                     "Gillespie",
                                     "Blanco",
                                     "Lee",
                                     "Travis",
                                     "Williamson",
                                     "Llano",
                                     "Mason",
                                     "Burnet"]

        # Model folder parameter
        model_folder = arcpy.Parameter(
            displayName="Model Location on Disk Where Data Is Stored",
            name="model_folder",
            datatype="Folder",
            parameterType="Required",
            direction="Input")

        model_folder.value = r'C:\model'

        # Urban Growth Model parameter
        # Plat parameter
        plat_features = arcpy.Parameter(
            displayName="Plat Features",
            name="plat_features",
            datatype="Feature Class",
            parameterType="Required",
            direction="Input",
            enabled=False)

        # Plat category field parameter
        category = arcpy.Parameter(
            displayName="Category Field from the Plat Features",
            name="category",
            datatype="Field",
            parameterType="Required",
            direction="Input",
            enabled=False)

        # Plat area size in square feet field parameter
        area_size = arcpy.Parameter(
            displayName="Area Size Field from the Plat Features",
            name="category",
            datatype="Field",
            parameterType="Required",
            direction="Input",
            enabled=False)

        # Plat dwell unit field parameter
        dwell_unit = arcpy.Parameter(
            displayName="Dwell unit Field from the Plat Features",
            name="dwell_unit",
            datatype="Field",
            parameterType="Required",
            direction="Input",
            enabled=False)

        # Energy Sector Model parameter
        # Oil well parameter
        oilWell = arcpy.Parameter(
            displayName="Oil Well Features",
            name="oilWell",
            datatype="Feature Class",
            parameterType="Required",
            direction="Input",
            enabled=False)

        # Disposal well parameter
        disposalWell = arcpy.Parameter(
            displayName="Disoposal Well Features",
            name="disposalWell",
            datatype="Feature Class",
            parameterType="Required",
            direction="Input",
            enabled=False)

        # Quarry parameter
        quarry = arcpy.Parameter(
            displayName="Quarry Features",
            name="quarry",
            datatype="Feature Class",
            parameterType="Required",
            direction="Input",
            enabled=False)

        # Water well parameter
        waterWell = arcpy.Parameter(
            displayName="Water Well Features",
            name="waterWell",
            datatype="Feature Class",
            parameterType="Required",
            direction="Input",
            enabled=False)

        # Texas counties parameter
        tx_county = arcpy.Parameter(
            displayName="Texas Counties Features",
            name="tx_county",
            datatype="Feature Class",
            parameterType="Required",
            direction="Input",
            enabled=True)

        # Linear reference parameter
        linear_ref = arcpy.Parameter(
            displayName="Linear Reference Features",
            name="linear_ref",
            datatype="Feature Class",
            parameterType="Required",
            direction="Input",
            enabled=True)

        # Tiger dataset folder parameter
        tiger_folder = arcpy.Parameter(
            displayName="TIGER Dataset Location",
            name="tiger_folder",
            datatype="Folder",
            parameterType="Required",
            direction="Input",
            enabled=True)

        # Buffer size parameter
        buffer_size = arcpy.Parameter(
            displayName="Buffer Size Around the Incidents",
            name="buffer_size",
            datatype="String",
            parameterType="Required",
            direction="Input",
            enabled=True)

        buffer_size.value = "20"

        parameters = [model_type,
                      target_county,
                      model_folder,
                      plat_features,
                      category,
                      area_size,
                      dwell_unit,
                      oilWell,
                      disposalWell,
                      quarry,
                      waterWell,
                      tx_county,
                      linear_ref,
                      tiger_folder,
                      buffer_size]

        return parameters

    def isLicensed(self): #optional
        return True

    def updateParameters(self, parameters): #optional
        if(parameters[0].value == "Urban Growth Model"):
            parameters[1].enabled = True
            parameters[3].enabled = True
            parameters[4].enabled = True
            parameters[5].enabled = True
            parameters[6].enabled = True
            parameters[7].enabled = False
            parameters[8].enabled = False
            parameters[9].enabled = False
            parameters[10].enabled = False
        elif(parameters[0].value == "Energy Sector Model"):
            parameters[1].enabled = False
            parameters[3].enabled = False
            parameters[4].enabled = False
            parameters[5].enabled = False
            parameters[6].enabled = False
            parameters[7].enabled = True
            parameters[8].enabled = True
            parameters[9].enabled = True
            parameters[10].enabled = True
        return

    def updateMessages(self, parameters): #optional
        return

    def execute(self, parameters, messages):
        """The source code of the tool."""
        return
```

Comment: Please clarify your question for us. Do you mean that if certain conditions are met, then the parameters will completely disappear from the tool window? The pic you supplied looks like the four parameters are grayed out. This means that no matter what the user does, they cannot enter anything into them. They are as good as not there. But when they enter something else that doesn't meet your conditions now they are active and can accept parameters. This sounds pretty good to me! Why does it matter if they are there or not if they can't be used?

Comment: Yes, I want to make them totally disappeared from the tool window and make the tool window clean. You are right, it doesn't matter with the function of the tool, but just a matter of personal preference.

Comment: Others may disagree, but there is no way to do this in a PYT. One alternative is to create two tools that hone in on what you really want to do. As with all development, you need to be clear on your scope and implementation. What will having one tool that does everything serve? Will having two tools that do similar things be any better? You know, I created a suite of tools once. They each shared about three functions and each had one or two that were unique. The UI benefited from dividing the big tool into three. Developers need to see the big picture and UX Just a suggestion! Happy coding!

Comment: For reference: [UI/UX] (https://www.usability.gov/what-and-why/user-interface-design.html)

@PolyGeo Should I make my comments into an answer or is this not a "real" answer to Tianxin's question?

Comment: @keepaustinbeard Thanks for your information. Now I know there is no way to do what I want with Python Toolbox.

Comment: @keepaustinbeard I think that would be fine to add as an answer. It is important to say when we think an asker is heading in the wrong direction with their question.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot actually remove a parameter from the dialog window because parameters are initialized in the `getParameterInfo` method.

The closest thing you can do is to put parameters you think might get disabled into a special [`category`](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/creating-tools/defining-parameters-in-a-python-toolbox.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_4BB1F5030E8645F0985630DC835D94B5) (named `optional parameters` or similar). When the user will start the tool, those parameters that under this category will be under the category.

This is done in the `getParameterInfo` method:

```
values.category = 'Optional params'
```

[image]